# How can I check for more corrupted Solr indexed nodes in Alfresco?

Tags: solr, alfresco

We found a bug in DIT where a CMIS query returned some nodes in archive://SpacesStore among many seemingly valid nodes.
Using CMIS workbench, when I clicked on an archived nodes' objectId, CMIS workbench said that that node could not be found.

The query used in_tree like this:

`SELECT * FROM <model> WHERE IN_TREE('6fd7f269-9d44-40a3-9152-1b89d6a3d07c')`

Alfresco support suggested that our Solr index could be corrupted, and that we could simply reindex.  I preferred to surgically fix the problem, so I ended up doing this:

1. Look up node ids in the database, and run the reindex script on each.

   `select n.id as node_id, n.UUID
   from alf_node n
   where n.uuid in ('a06d87d6-e49a-4f85-b5c3-2e68a81ad760',
                    'b6bb26d1-aaf2-4a80-8ce9-8aae93f89d9d',
                    '10951fbd-f2ab-4247-89c1-b050aa00a4f9')`
2. I found two db node ids per uuid, so I did some more digging.

   `1724775 b6bb26d1-aaf2-4a80-8ce9-8aae93f89d9d
   1724776 b6bb26d1-aaf2-4a80-8ce9-8aae93f89d9d
   1726270 10951fbd-f2ab-4247-89c1-b050aa00a4f9
   1726271 10951fbd-f2ab-4247-89c1-b050aa00a4f9
   1726260 a06d87d6-e49a-4f85-b5c3-2e68a81ad760
   1726261 a06d87d6-e49a-4f85-b5c3-2e68a81ad760`
3. Those nodes had some properties with string_value that started with 'workspace'

   `select n.id as node_id, n.uuid
   from alf_node_properties p, alf_node
   where n.uuid in ('a06d87d6-e49a-4f85-b5c3-2e68a81ad760'
                    'b6bb26d1-aaf2-4a80-8ce9-8aae93f89d9d',
                    '10951fbd-f2ab-4247-89c1-b050aa00a4f9')
   and p.STRING_VALUE like 'workspace%'
   and n.id = p.node_id;`
4. I used these node ids to send to Solr

   `1724775 b6bb26d1-aaf2-4a80-8ce9-8aae93f89d9d
   1726270 10951fbd-f2ab-4247-89c1-b050aa00a4f9
   1726260 a06d87d6-e49a-4f85-b5c3-2e68a81ad760`

`http://<solr_host>/solr/admin/cores?action=REINDEX&nodeid=1724775`
`http://<solr_host>/solr/admin/cores?action=REINDEX&nodeid=1726270`
`http://<solr_host>/solr/admin/cores?action=REINDEX&nodeid=1726260`

5. Each time I got this response:

> ```
> <response>
> <lst name="responseHeader">
> <int name="status">0</int>
> <int name="QTime">0</int>
> </lst>
> </response>
> ```

6. Rerun 
   `SELECT * FROM <model> WHERE IN_TREE('6fd7f269-9d44-40a3-9152-1b89d6a3d07c')`
   in CMIS workbench with max hits 1000. 
   Scroll through the results, and find no more archive records.

I cleaned up the corrupted indexed nodes that I found from that CMIS search, but how can I find such corrupted nodes throughout my index?  I tried to add criteria to my search to specify only those nodes, but that just resulted in an empty result set.  Can anyone explain how or why this could have happened and **How can I check for more corrupted Solr indexed nodes in Alfresco?**

By the way, we are still on Alfresco 4.2 and Solr 1